# Traveling in March and returning in March with a Schengen visa that expires in April

Tags: visas, schengen, france

Is it fine to travel in March with a Schengen visa that expires the next month. Return to SA will still be in March.

Comment: Yes unless there are other reasons you haven't revealed.

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't it be? The last time I looked at a calendar, April came after March.